# How to determine why an R script is not working?

Tags: r

I am trying to run this file and plot the based on the value, I have also  used the ui.R script for opening a file.

```
library(shiny)
library (flowCore)
library(flowViz)  

shinyServer (function(input, output,server){
# trying to open a file 
ff <- input$file
str(input$file)
 # to read a fcs file from a flow cytometer
read.FCS("input$file",
       transformation="linearize",
       alter.names=FALSE,
       column.pattern=NULL,
       invert.pattern = FALSE,
       decades=0,
       ncdf=FALSE,                      min.limit=NULL,
       truncate_max_range = TRUE,
       dataset=NULL,
       emptyValue=TRUE )

 filedata <- reactive
 ({
 ff <- input$file
 str(input$file)

              read.FCS("input$file",
               transformation="linearize",
               alter.names=FALSE,
               column.pattern=NULL,
               invert.pattern = FALSE,
               decades=0,
               ncdf=FALSE,                      min.limit=NULL,
               truncate_max_range = TRUE,
               dataset=NULL,
               emptyValue=TRUE )
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot
  ({
  lg <- rectangleGate("FS INT LIN"=c(350,700),"SS INT LIN"=c(50,250))

  lymp <- Subset(ff,lg)
  # to compensate the values
  bx<-biexponentialTransform()
  bx1<-transformList(c("FL1 INT LOG","FL4 INT LOG"),bx)
  bx2<-transformList(c("FL4 INT LOG","FL2 INT LOG"),bx)
  bx3<-transformList(c("FL4 INT LOG","FL3 INT LOG"),bx)
  CD45CD3<-transform(lymp,bx1)
  CD3CD4<-transform(lymp,bx2)
  CD3CD8<-transform(lymp,bx3)

  # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
  plot (ff, c("FS INT LIN","SS INT LIN"),xlim = c(100,1050),ylim=c(-10,900), 
  nbin=260)
  xyplot(`SS INT LIN` ~ `FS INT LIN`,ff,filter=lg)
  plot(lymp, c("FL1 INT LOG","FL2 INT LOG"),xlim = c(100,1050),ylim= 
  c(-10,900), nbin=260)
  })
  # i want to run this app
  })
  shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
 runApp("flowcyto", display.mode = "showcase")   
 }
 )
```

I have tried to use a few posts I have seen here but none seem to be working. I am working on trying to recreate a flow cyto based analysis system for automation, the first step is to call the file and plot the respective plot.
The error I am getting is:

```
Warning: Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext: Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
Stack trace (innermost first):
    46: .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext
    45: .subset2(x, "impl")$get
    44: $.reactivevalues
    43: $ [C:\Users\ramaswamynathan.v\Desktop\r script\flowcyto/server.R#14]
    42: server [C:\Users\ramaswamynathan.v\Desktop\r script\flowcyto/server.R#14]
     1: runApp
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
```

library(shiny)

```
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
shinyUI(fluidPage(

# Application title
titlePanel("FLOW CYTOMETRY DATA"),

titlePanel("Flow Cytometry"),
# Upload File  
fileInput("file", label = h3("File input")),

hr(),
fluidRow(column(4, verbatimTextOutput("value")))
```

))
 my UI page for now is just to open the file from a location and use it to run my program.

Comment: I've tidied your question up a bit, but broadly I think you're saying this is "not working". When it comes down to it, that's not a very specific fault report, so would you be more specific? What does the script do? Does it run? Does it produce wrong results? In what way are they wrong? (I have trimmed a secondary question about multiple plots, as that feels like an unrelated question that can be researched, and asked about if necessary, after you've resolved this issue).

Comment: the page loads and shows me the following error, thanks a lot for you help

Answer (score 0):

To determine why a R script is not working you just have to read the error or copy/paste it in your browser if you really don't understand.

So your main question shouldn't be this and you don't even say that it's a `shiny` problem which is a specific package that not all R users knows.

For your shiny problem, R is saying that you do not respect the `shiny`'s `reactive` approach. In fact, there is a lot of errors which I corrected here :

```
library(shiny)
library (flowCore)
library(flowViz)  

server <- shinyServer (function(input, output){
# trying to open a file     
 filedata <- reactive
 ({
 ff <- input$file
 return(read.FCS("input$file",
               transformation="linearize",
               alter.names=FALSE,
               column.pattern=NULL,
               invert.pattern = FALSE,
               decades=0,
               ncdf=FALSE,                      min.limit=NULL,
               truncate_max_range = TRUE,
               dataset=NULL,
               emptyValue=TRUE ))})
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot
  ({
  lg <- rectangleGate("FS INT LIN"=c(350,700),"SS INT LIN"=c(50,250))

  lymp <- Subset(filedata(),lg)
  # to compensate the values
  bx<-biexponentialTransform()
  bx1<-transformList(c("FL1 INT LOG","FL4 INT LOG"),bx)
  bx2<-transformList(c("FL4 INT LOG","FL2 INT LOG"),bx)
  bx3<-transformList(c("FL4 INT LOG","FL3 INT LOG"),bx)
  CD45CD3<-transform(lymp,bx1)
  CD3CD4<-transform(lymp,bx2)
  CD3CD8<-transform(lymp,bx3)

  # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
  plot (filedata(), c("FS INT LIN","SS INT LIN"),xlim = c(100,1050),ylim=c(-10,900), 
  nbin=260)
  xyplot(`SS INT LIN` ~ `FS INT LIN`,ff,filter=lg)
  plot(lymp, c("FL1 INT LOG","FL2 INT LOG"),xlim = c(100,1050),ylim= 
  c(-10,900), nbin=260)
  })
  # i want to run this app
  })
      shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

But the problem is that there is a lot of other confusions that I can not correct. For exemple in your `renderPlot` you are doing three plots...

For your mistakes you passed `server` in `shinyServer` which is absolutely absurd. You also include the `renderPlot` in the `reactive`  You call `shinyApp` in your server part. Have you even an `ui` part ??? If yes you should add it to your post because I suppose that it contains errors. I can't be sure that the correction is exhaustive because without an `ui`part it can not be tried.

I strongly recommand you to have a look to the [shiny homepage](https://shiny.rstudio.com/).

Comment: thanks a lot, i am just trying to get a hang of it I have been looking at the homepage and get confused. sorry for troubling you

Comment: I'm not troubled :) try to do little apllications in a first place to more understand the not intuitive shiny approach.

Comment: thanks, I have been thrust upon this at the last min hence i am too confused